# What's required to implement root class of Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class, objective-c-runtime, llvm-clang

I tried this code:

```
// main.m
#import <stdio.h>

@interface Test 
+ (void)test;
@end
@implementation Test
+ (void)test
{
    printf("test");
}
@end

int main()
{
    [Test test];
    return  0;
}
```

with LLVM/Clang without any framework, it doesn't compiled with this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So I added `libobjc.dylib`. Code compiled, but threw this runtime exception:

```
objc[13896]: Test: Does not recognize selector forward::
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION”.

#0  0x9932a4b4 in _objc_error
#1  0x9932a4ea in __objc_error
#2  0x993212b6 in _objc_msgForward
#3  0x99321299 in _objc_msgForward
#4  0x99321510 in _class_initialize
#5  0x99328972 in prepareForMethodLookup
#6  0x99329c17 in lookUpMethod
#7  0x99321367 in _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache
#8  0x99320f13 in objc_msgSend
#9  0x00001ee5 in start
```

I realized some implementation required for root class, but I don't know what should I do next. What's required to make a new root class? And is there any specification for this?

Comment: I found a valuable resource: http://code.google.com/p/purefoundation/ 
However, still don't know about specifications.

Comment: Just for later reference; Apple's open-sourced objc runtime source contains `NSObject` source too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just came to this question because I had the same "academic" question. After working through it a bit, I have found that the other answers to this question aren't completely correct.

It is true that **on the Apple Objective-C 2.0 runtime**, you must implement certain methods in order for your code to work. There is actually only one method that you need to implement: the class method `initialize`.

```
@interface MyBase 
+ (void)test;
@end
@implementation MyBase
+ (void)initialize {}
+ (void)test {
 // whatever
}
@end
```

The runtime will automatically call `initialize` when you first use your class (as explained [in Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize)). Not implementing this method is the reason for the message forwarding error.

Compiling with `clang test.m -Wall -lobjc` (or gcc) will allow you to call the class method test without any issue. Making object allocation work is a different story. At the very least, you'll need an `isa` pointer on your base class if you're using instance variables. The runtime expects this to be there.

Comment: You're right. It works! Thanks, this is a huge step for me :)

Answer (score 2):

**On the Apple runtime**, the minimum specs are pretty easily explained: You have to implement *every* method in the `NSObject` protocol. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject). This is absolutely **non-trivial**. You might want to add a couple of additional functions like `+alloc` in order to be able to create an instance, etc. There are only two public root classes in all of Apple's frameworks: [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObject) and [`NSProxy`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In practice, there is absolutely no reason to create a root class. I'm not sure there is any documentation to this issue by Apple.

What you will do in practice is to inherit from `NSObject` or `NSProxy` and build on top of them. Your code will work if you do the following:

```
@interface Test : NSObject
+ (void)test;
@end
```

As Tilo pointed out, this is not the case on other runtimes like the GNU runtime.

Comment: You are right Max: Implementing a new root class is challenging and can be interesting from an academical point of view, but practically there are only very few applications.

Comment: In reality Apple has created only 5 root classes in all Cocoa frameworks, including nsobject and nsproxy. I never had the need to create one on my own.

Comment: It was just a kind of trial making objc program on non-Apple platform (like FreeBSD). I agreee with there's no reason to make my own root class in Apple platform :)

Comment: There are different root classes on different platforms. Most other distributions either include `NSObject` or feature a root class called `object`. YOu might want to google for that...

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. The above example compiles fine with gcc and GNU-runtime. In Objective-C normally any class can be a root class by simply not having a super class. If the Apple-runtime requires something different, then it's runtime specific.

Comment: @Tilo. I find your response a bit drastic, but yes, I assumed the Apple runtime. As assumed he was wanting to target that runtime, since he ran it on there. Is the gnu runtime still being used anyways?

Comment: @Max: Of course it (the GNU runtime) is :). And maybe I was drastic but I think it should be clearly said that there is a difference between the language Objective-C as understood and processed by the compilers and the different runtimes. And if you'll edit your answer to point this one out I'll take back my down vote :).

Comment: And back to the topic: Is the NSObject protocol part of the Apple runtime or of the Foundation Framework? If the latter the runtime should not expect a root class to implement it.

Comment: It is part of the framework but it required by the runtime. In fact, a lot of functionality of the runtime is linked to the framework. I'm pretty sure it wouldn't make too much sense to use either separately.

Comment: Woah! I think that's bad (or at least suboptimal ;)) design. IMHO if framework and runtime require each other they should be put together. At this point the GNU runtime is better. It brings a minimum amount of classes to start with and does not rely on the architecture of a specific framework build on top of it.

Comment: Yep, see this the same way. Theoretically one could simply move a few headers and classes out of the framework into the runtime and that'd be fixed...

Answer (score 2):

In my system (GNUstep on linux + GCC) I had to replace the above alloc method with the following, to make the sample work. I think this is due to a newer obj-c runtime (documentation of the runtime here: [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_createInstance) from the Mac Developer Library.

```
+ alloc
{
  return (id)class_createInstance(self, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above example compiles fine with gcc and GNU-runtime. In Objective-C normally any class can be a root class by simply not having a super class. If the Apple-runtime requires something different, then it's runtime specific.

Additionally there is something specific with root classes:

All instance methods are also class methods with the same implementation (if not explicitly implemented otherwise). The output of the following app:

```
#import <stdio.h>

@interface Test
+ alloc;
+ (void)test;
- (void)test;
- (void)otherTest;
@end
@implementation Test
+ alloc
{
  return (id)class_create_instance(self);
}

+ (void)test
{
    printf("class test\n");
}

- (void)test
{
    printf("instance test\n");
}

- (void)otherTest
{
    printf("otherTest\n");
}
@end

int main()
{
    id t = [Test alloc];
    [Test test];
    [t test];
    [Test otherTest];
    [t otherTest];
    return  0;
}
```

would be:

```
class test
instance test
otherTest
otherTest
```

The hardest part on creating a new root class is the `+alloc` and `-dealloc` but as seen in my example the runtime (in my case the GNU-runtime) can do this. But I don't know if the runtime allocation is good enough. I know that some foundations use an own allocation mechanism to hide the reference counter from the object structure. I don't know if Apple does this too and if their runtime already takes care of it.