# Class without superclass in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to create a class in Objective-C without a superclass.

If I create something like

```
@interface Samp
@end
```

I get the error message: "Class Samp defined without specifying a base class".
How come NSProxy compiles?

Answer (score 3):

The pedantic answer is yes, you can. You just have to make your class a root class, which you can do by using the compiler attribute `objc_root_class`.

```
 __attribute__((objc_root_class))
@interface Samp
@end
```

or using the convenience macro `NS_ROOT_CLASS`

```
NS_ROOT_CLASS
@interface Samp 
@end
```

This is the same thing `NSProxy` does.

```
NS_ROOT_CLASS
@interface NSProxy <NSObject> {
    Class   isa;
}
```

Now, unless you're doing something really specific and out of the schemes, I don't see why you would want to do that.

Juts make your class to inherit from an existing root class, like `NSObject` (the most common) or `NSProxy`.

Answer (score 2):

> How come `NSProxy` compiles?

`NSProxy` class is special - it is one of Cocoa's two public root classes (`NSObject` is the other one). If you must define your own root class, [this answer tells you how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4796925/335858). However, in practice there should be no reason to implement your own root class.