# Why is there no universal base class in Swift?

Tags: swift

The documentation says

> NOTE
>
> Swift classes do not inherit from a universal base class. Classes you
>   define without specifying a superclass automatically become base
>   classes for you to build upon.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “[The Swift Programming Language.](https://itun.es/at/jEUH0.l)” iBooks.

It doesn't make much sense to me. There is a reason why Objective-C has a universal base class, and the same reason should apply to Swift, does it? `NSObject` manages retain/release semantics, a default implementation for `isEqual:`, `hash` and `description`. All this functionality is available in Swift too.

(Objective-C and Swift use the same runtime...)

So, what's up with that? Are Swift classes with no defined superclasses just `NSObject`s that pose as proper root classes under the hood? Or is the default object-behaviour duplicated for each new root-class? Or have they created another Swift-baseclass? The implementation of `retain` and `release` is really complex, because it needs to take multithreading and weak references into account at the same time.

Is there maybe a universal base class in Swift (despite what the documentation says)? It would be really handy, because in Objective-C I can e.g. write extensions that let me coalesce method invocations to the main runloop like `[obj.eventually updateCounter]` which can be read as "call `-updateCounter` the next time the main runloop gets in control. If, in the meantime, I call this method again, it should be called only once anyways. With this extension one could implement `-[UIView setNeedsDisplay]` as `[self.eventually display];` This is no longer possible in Swift if there is no universal base class (or maybe it is, who knows?)

Comment: I feel this is too opinion based, I'm not sure how anyone can answer without asking the language designers...

Comment: parts of it may be opinion-based, but most is not. E.g. "Are Swift classes with no defined superclasses just NSObjects that pose as proper root classes under the hood? Or is the default object-behaviour duplicated for each new root-class? Or have they created another Swift-baseclass?" is clearly not asking for an opinion...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are several object-oriented languages where one can define new root classes, including C++, PHP, and Objective-C, and they work fine, so this is definitely not a special thing.

> There is a reason why Objective-C has a universal base class

As Sulthan mentioned, this is not true. There are multiple root classes in Objective-C, and you can define a new root class by simply not specifying a superclass. As Sulthan also mentioned, Cocoa itself has several root classes, `NSObject`, `NSProxy`, and `Object` (the root class of `Protocol` in ObjC 1.0).

The original Objective-C language was very flexible and someone could in theory come along and create his own root class and create his own framework that is completely different from Foundation, and uses methods completely different from `retain`, `release`, `alloc`, `dealloc`, etc., and could even implement a completely different way of memory management if he wanted. This flexibility is one of the things so amazing about the bare Objective-C language -- it simply provides a thin layer, all the other things like how objects are created and destroyed, memory management, etc., can all be determined by the user frameworks sitting on top.

However, with Apple's Objective-C 2.0 and modern runtime, [more work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582209/whats-required-to-implement-root-class-of-objective-c) needed to be done to make your own root class. And with the addition of ARC, in order to use your objects in ARC, you must implement Cocoa's memory management methods like `retain` and `release`. Also, to use your objects in Cocoa collections, your class must also implement things like `isEqual:` and `hash`.

So in modern Cocoa/Cocoa Touch development, objects generally must at least implement a basic set of methods, which are the methods in the `NSObject` protocol. All the root classes in Cocoa (`NSObject`, `NSProxy`) implement the `NSObject` protocol.

> So, what's up with that? Are Swift classes with no defined
>   superclasses just NSObjects that pose as proper root classes under the
>   hood? Or is the default object-behaviour duplicated for each new
>   root-class? Or have they created another Swift-baseclass?

This is a good question, and you can find out by introspection with the Objective-C runtime. All objects in Swift are, in a sense, also Objective-C objects, in that they can be used with the Objective-C runtime just like objects from Objective-C. Some members of the class (the ones not marked `@objc` or `dynamic`) may not be visible to Objective-C, but otherwise all the introspection features of the Objective-C runtime work fully on objects of pure Swift classes. Classes defined in Swift look like any other class to the Objective-C runtime, except the name is mangled.

Using the Objective-C runtime, you can discover that for a class that is a root class in Swift, from the point of view of Objective-C, it actually has a superclass named `SwiftObject`. And this `SwiftObject` class implements the methods of the `NSObject` protocol like `retain`, `release`, `isEqual:`, `respondsToSelector:`, etc. (though it does not actually conform to the `NSObject` protocol). This is how you can use pure Swift objects with Cocoa APIs without problem.

From inside Swift itself, however, the compiler does not believe that a Swift root class implements these methods. So if you define a root class `Foo`, then if you try to call `Foo().isKindOfClass(Foo.self)`, it will not compile it complaining that this method does not exist. But we can still use it with a trick -- recall that the compiler will let us call any Objective-C method (which the compiler has heard of) on a variable of type `AnyObject`, and the method lookup produces an implicitly-unwrapped optional function that succeeds or fails at runtime. So what we can do is cast to `AnyObject`, make sure to import `Foundation` or `ObjectiveC` (so the declaration is visible to the compiler), we can then call it, and it will work at runtime:

```
(Foo() as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(Foo.self)
```

So basically, from the Objective-C point of view, a Swift class either has an existing Objective-C class as root class (if it inherited from an Objective-C class), or has `SwiftObject` as root class.

Answer (score 30):

This is mainly a **design decision**, there are languages which have a root class (e.g. Java) and languages which don't (e.g. C++).

Note that in Obj-C a root class is not enforced. You can easily create an object which doesn't inherit from any class. You can also create your own root classes, there are at least 3 in the Apple API (`NSObject`, `NSProxy` and deprecated `Object`).

The reason to have a root class is mostly historical - the root class ensures that all objects have some common interface, some common methods (e.g. `isEqualTo:`, `hash()` etc.) which are necessary for collection classes to work.

Once you have generics (or templates in C++), having a root class is not so important any more.

`retain` and `release` in `NSObject` are not important anymore since ARC. With MRC, you were still required to call them. With ARC you never call the methods explicitly and they can be implemented more efficiently behind the scenes.

In Swift, the methods from `NSObject` have been divided into protocols - `Equatable`, `Hashable`, `Printable` and `DebugPrintable`. That has the advantage that objects can share interfaces with structs.

However, there is nothing stopping you from inheriting every class from `NSObject`. The class is still there and it is especially useful if you are dealing with Obj-C APIs. In pure Swift, a root class is not necessary though.

One more note:

Swift classes doesn't run on top of Obj-C; they are not translated into Obj-C behind the scenes. They are just compiled by the same compiler which allows them to interoperate with each other. That's really important to understand. That's why `@objc` must be sometimes added to provide consistency with Obj-C protocols/classes.

Comment: the problem is that these self created base classes cannot participate in ARC unless I implement much of NSObjects functionality. A Swift-root-class can be used in much the same way as an NSObject-derived subclass can in Objective-C!

Comment: In C++ you don't have any kind of memory-management built into the language/ecosystem. In Objective-C you use `NSObject`-functionality all the time. ARC has methods like `objc_storeStrong`, but in the object there has to be some kind of `retainCount` iVar anyways. And `==` is available for all Swift classes.

Comment: @Michael `==` is not available for all Swift classes. It's implemented only by classes conforming to protocol `Equatable`. The implementation of `retainCount` doesn't need a base class. It's probable that all objects have some common memory layout but that's an implementation detail and it's not required to create a base class for it.

Comment: so the answer would be "all objects contain two iVars at the start: `isa` and `retainCount`. ARC just accesses this `retainCount` through something like `((int)((int*)((void **)obj+1)))` and therefore no `-retain` or `-release` methods are needed. Trying to use `-description`, e.g. through string-interpolation, will produce a crash for such an object." but, is it true?

Comment: @Michael No. That's an implementation detail. For example, they could wrap every object by a structure providing the details and reference count. This is like guessing how a garbage collector is implemented. It's true there must be a `retainCount` somewhere but it doesn't have to be part of the class, it doesn't have to be even close (you can put it into a shared dictionary per reference, for example). Using `description` is always possible on classes implementing `Printable` protocol. On other classes the compiler won't let you do it.

Comment: *Swift classes doesn't run on Obj-C runtime.* Are you sure about that? Everything I've read from Apple and elsewhere says that [Swift uses the same runtime that Objective-C does](http://www.smashingboxes.com/apples-swift-a-developers-first-impression/).

Comment: @Caleb I meant to say that Swift is not a layer over Obj-C, they are side by side. I'll try to be more precise.

Comment: @Caleb that's what I remember too. IMHO Obj-C is just syntactic sugar for the Obj-C runtime + a few safety checks. E.g. `[obj foo]` becomes `objc_msgSend(obj, @selector(foo));`. On the other hand, Swift has to be compiled down to some C or assembler code + some calls to the ObjC-runtime. It's much more than just syntactic sugar above the ObjC-runtime. Although I can understand that Swift doesn't require classes to be inherited from NSObject, I don't understand why this decision was actually made. What does it buy us when we not inherit from NSObject? Performance-wise or otherwise...

Comment: I can only imagine inherently unsafe stuff to implement with a new root class. And Swift was meant to be a safe, managed, language. (Of course you can just implement a subset of `NSObject` functionality and it would maybe be safe, but what's the point in that?) For example you could create two objects that share a cyclic reference with each other, and once both are no longer referenced from the outside both objects go away simultanuously... That's the kind of stuff where a new root class may help...

Comment: @Michael Well, Swift allows methods on structs and structs cannot inherit from any object so one gain from replacing the root class with protocols (`Equatable` etc.) is the possibility to share interfaces between structs and classes. One problem with not having a root class is that you have to use that annoying `@class_protocol` for protocols that can be implemented only by classes. However, mostly there is no exact reason, it's a random decision. For example, C# has a root class and it has basically the same features as Swift.

Comment: @Caleb, Michael, Swift classes aren't ObjC classes. They can, however, be made to look like ObjC classes very easily. Swift classes have an entry in the list of ObjC classes containing a version of their name that ObjC can deal with, but that's it. It doesn't list Swift methods at all, unless you mark it as `@objc` or subclass an ObjC class. Method dispatch in Swift is completely different than in ObjC. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii-02vhsdVk

Comment: i agree, this was a design decision. a bad one (my opinion). because swift doesn't have a universal base class i use NSObject sometimes, and this of course means that my swift code is not at all disentangled from the (awesomeness imho) of objective-c. that's not good.

Comment: @spnkr I think you are doing it wrong. Why do you even need a base class?