# Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'String' operands

Tags: swift

Why can't the === be used with String's in Swift?  I am unable to compile the following:

```
let string1 = "Bob"
let string2 = "Fred"

if string1 === string2 {
    ...
}
```

and get the following error (on the if line):

> Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'String' operands

---

What I want to be able to do in my unit tests is, having performed a copyWithZone:, verify that two objects are indeed a different object with different pointers even if their values are the same.  The following code doesn't work...

> XCTAssertFalse(object1.someString === object2.someString)

If anyone knows of an alternative way please advise.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide (a minimal example of) your actual code: the class with the copyWithZone method and the unit test.

Answer (score 8):

string1 and string2 are not NSString, but String. Since they are value objects, not reference objects, there is no reference that could be compared with ===.

Answer (score 5):

Swift's `===` operator, by default, is only defined for classes.

Swift's `String` type is not a class but a struct. It does not inherit from `AnyObject` and therefore cannot be compared by reference.

You could of course implement an `===` operator for `String` in Swift, but I'm not sure how it would be any different from the implementation of `==` for Swift's `String` type.

```
func ===(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}
```

Unless, of course, you *really* wanted to compare the references, I suppose you could do something like this:

```
func ===(lhs: String, rhs: String) -> Bool {
    return unsafeAddressOf(lhs) == unsafeAddressOf(rhs)
}
```

However, for the sake of tests, rather than using the `==` or `===` operators, you should use the appropriate assertions:

```
XCTAssertEqual(foo, bar)
XCTAssertNotEqual(foo, bar)
```

Comment: They're struct's in Swift, who knew! 
Thank you for attempting to address my testing issue however I think my problems are bigger than this because I am trying to test in Swift a class that is defined in Objective-C so the class does use NSString objects in real life but in my tests its converted to Swift String primatives.

Comment: unsafeAddressOf() is pretty useless with Swift Strings, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638879/swift-strings-and-memory-addresses.

Comment: Is it valid to imply that Swift classes inherit from `AnyObject`? You can cast any class to an AnyObject, but I'm not sure it's right to say that they inherit from it. Or is this wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137368/why-is-there-no-universal-base-class-in-swift

Comment: @Grimxn: `String` is not a class, but a struct. *Some* types (String, Int, Float, ...) are automatically bridged to Foundation classes (NSString, NSNumber, ...) if Foundation is imported.

Comment: Martin, I know that, but @nhgrif implies in his answer that Swift *classes* inherit from `AnyObject`. Second paragraph, second sentence.

Comment: AnyObject is a *protocol* to which all classes implicitly conform.

Answer (score 3):

The === operator is the identity operator. It checks if two variables or constants refer to the same **instance of a class**. Strings are not classes (they are structs) so the === operator does not apply to them.

If you want to check if two strings are the same, use the equality operator == instead.

Read all about the identity operator in the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID90).

You can just check two objects for identity directly, instead of checking a property of type String.

```
 XCTAssertFalse(object1 === object2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift Strings are value type, not reference type, so there's no need for that, a copy will always be a different object.

You should just compare by value with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try really hard, you can force things to happen, but I'm not sure what that buys you.

```
class MyClass: NSObject, NSCopying {
    var someString: NSString = ""

    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let copy = self.dynamicType.init()
        copy.someString = someString.copy() as? NSString ?? ""
        return copy
    }
}

let object1 = MyClass()
object1.someString = NSString(format: "%d", arc4random())
let object2 = object1.copy()

if object1.someString === object2.someString {
    print("identical")
} else {
    print("different")
}
```

prints `identical`, the system is really good at conserving strings.