# Root class of all classes in Swift?

Tags: swift, class

The Apple's developer documentation says:

> NSObject is
>   The root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies, from which subclasses inherit a basic interface to the runtime system.

I wonder what is the root class of all classes in Swift in the example below:

```
class MyClass {
....
}
```

Comment: Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137368/why-is-there-no-universal-base-class-in-swift) It's possible a duplicate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26073524/5362750 check this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Swift classes do not inherit from a universal base class. Classes you
>   define without specifying a superclass automatically become base
>   classes for you to build upon.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

Is that what you were looking for? :)