# Is there an Object class in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am very new to Swift. Is there a generic all-encompassing Object class in Swift like there is in Java/C#?

Can I declare an array that can hold anything (Int/String/Character...etc)?

Comment: [Why is there no universal base class in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137368/why-is-there-no-universal-base-class-in-swift)

Comment: @MartinR That duplicate answers the first part of the question well, but the last sentence deserves its own answer. I was going to talk about `Any`, but how discriminated unions (`enum` in Swift) is usually a better choice

Comment: @Alexander: I closed as a duplicate only after OP said (in a now deleted comment) “Thanks, should I delete this question?” – You are free to reopen it.

Comment: I'll answer the unique part of this question (the latter part), and defer to your link for the former (duplicate) portion

Comment: @MartinR Curious question: suppose you were crazy enough to write a massive switch containing cases which attempt to conditionally cast an `Any` into every possible type the compiler knows about. Would the compiler be satisfied about the switch's exhaustivity?

Comment: @Alexander: With tuples alone you have infinitely many “possible types.”

Comment: @MartinR Good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in ["Why is there no universal base class in Swift?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137368/why-is-there-no-universal-base-class-in-swift), no, but there is a common protocol that every type implicitly conforms to: `Any`.

```
// A statically typed `Any` constant, that points to a value which
// has a runtime type of `Int`
let something: Any = 5 

// An array of `Any` things
let things: [Any] = [1, "string", false]

for thing in things {
    switch thing {
    case let i as Int: consumeInt(i)
    case let s as String: consumeString(s)
    case let b as Bool: consumeBool(b)

    // Because `Any` really does mean ANY type, the compiler can't prove
    // that this switch is exhaustive, unless we have a `default`
    default: fatalError("Got an unexpected type!")
    }
}
```

However, using `Any` is ill-advised most of the time. For most purposes, discriminated unions are a better choice, which Swift has in the form of enums. These ensure that all possible types are considered:

```
// Using an enum with associated values creates a discriminated union
// containing the exact set of type that we wish to support, rather than `Any`
enum SomeValue { // Note: this is a bad name, but just as an example!
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
    case bool(Bool)
}

let someValues: [SomeValue] = [.int(1), .string("string"), .bool(false)]

for value in someValues {
    switch value {
    case .int(let i): consumeInt(i)
    case .string(let s): consumeString(s)
    case .bool(let b): consumeBool(b)

    // Enums have finitely many cases, all of which we exhausted here
    // No `default` case required!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are `Any`and `AnyObject` types that are seem to what you search for. You can't extend them but you can up cast any object to `AnyObject` type and insert into `[AnyObject]` array. `Any` is more wide, and includes `Int`, `String`, `Bool`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, Swift does not have a generic Object Class.