# How to check is array of ANY contain which data type of element

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array like `[Any]`, I just append some `String` element And `UIImage` element.
at the end, I am listing it into `UITableView` where I need to show an image where index of array have `UIImage` and string where index of element have `String` type.

```
class PhotosVC: UIViewController {

    var arrPhotos: [Any] = [Any]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.arrPhotos.append("stringValue")
        self.arrPhotos.append(pickedImage)
        self.collectionViewData.reloadData()
    }
}
extension PhotosVC: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrPhotos.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotosDescCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosDescCell

        if arrPhotos[indexPath] == String { // how to check here is element is String type or UIImage
            cell.lblDesc.text = arrPhotos[indexPath] as? String
        }
        else {
            cell.imgPhotos.image = arrPhotos[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't combine different types within an Array like this. You either have to deal with the constant nuisance of safely casting, or risk making my mistakes by force casting.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844122/3141234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use ***is***

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotosDescCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotosDescCell

        if arrPhotos[indexPath] is String { 
            cell.lblDesc.text = arrPhotos[indexPath] as? String
        }
        else {
            cell.imgPhotos.image = arrPhotos[indexPath.row] as? UIImage
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do type-checking directly.  For example:

```
var arrPhotos = [Any]()
arrPhotos.append("Some string")
if let five = Int("5") {
    arrPhotos.append(five)
}

for value in arrPhotos {
    if value is String {
        print("String \(value)")
    } else if value is Int {
        print("Int \(value)")
    } else {
        print("Not interesting \(value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to use a `switch`, to actually cast and conditionally bind the values to be of a certain type

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by many ways like:

```
if arrPhotos[indexPath] is String { 
   cell.lblDesc.text = arrPhotos[indexPath.row] as? String
 }
```

**Or**: It also unwrap the value

```
if let textData = arrPhotos[indexPath.row] as? String {
       cell.lblDesc.text = textData
   }
```