# Extend a functionality for whole the classes

Tags: swift, swift4

Swift, is possible extend a functionality for whole the classes?

I mean, I'm trying to play (this haven't any real objective), I want to extend from my `class` or my `Codable`.

But, I get this error:

`extension AnyClass`

> Cannot extend a metatype 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')

It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but guessing I think you wish to be able to extend all classes in your program as you might in, say Objective-C, the equivalent does not exist in Swift.

In Objective-C/Cocoa the vast majority of classes[1] derive directly, or through ancestors, from the `NSObject` class - `NSObject` is called a *base class* (often used in relation to Objective-C & Swift) or a *root class* (often used in relation to Java and C#). By using an Objective-C *category* you can add methods to `NSObject` which are then inherited by all its subclasses.

Java and C#, among others, are languages which like Objective-C have a root class – `Object` & `System.Object` respectively.

Swift and the Swift Standard Library do not have a single base class, a class *may* be declared to inherit from a superclass but if no superclass is specified the class is a *base class*. Given there is no common base class there is no class you can extend which would result in methods being added to all types.

The Swift types `Any`, `AnyObject` and `AnyClass` are *not* class types and do not represent a base class. `AnyClass` is a metatype, that is the type of a type, and as your error messages says Swift does not support extension of metatypes.

HTH

---

[1] Objective-C itself does not define a common base class, in that way it is similar to Swift. However the primary (Apple) Cocoa framework does, in this it differs from the Swift Standard Library which does not.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer who fit with my problem

[Why is there no universal base class in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137368/why-is-there-no-universal-base-class-in-swift)

There are multiple root classes in Objective-C, and you can define a new root class by simply not specifying a superclass. As Sulthan also mentioned, Cocoa itself has several root classes, `NSObject`, `NSProxy`, and `Object` (the root class of `Protocol` in `ObjC 1.0`).